# Azure Synapse Analytics - exception Running a Dataflow

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Using the preview of Synapse Analytics Workspace and the relates Synapse Studio, I have created a Data Flow that simply loads parquet file from a Datalake gen2 store into a table inside a SQL pool . Running the pipeline that contains only suchData Flow, I got the error

```
Livy Id=[0]  Job failed during run time with state=[dead].
```

In synapse studio, looking into **Monitor** -> **Apache Spark Application** I found the *Driver-stderr* log for the failed spark application. There there was a row stating

```
ERROR Dataflow AppManager: name=AppManager.main, opId=AppManager fail, unexpected:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.microsoft.azure.kusto.ingest.IngestionProperties.setJsonMappingName(Ljava/lang/String;)V, message=adfadf
```

Does any of you ever seen such error?

Comment: I've seen that error when running Spark Jobs in batch in Synapse, but never from a Data Flow.

Comment: Hi Joel, this is interesting. Did you manage to solve it? [Actually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview) is seems Data flow spins Apache Spark to execute

Comment: Data flow currently runs on Azure Databricks, so yes it relies on a Spark implementation. The problem I had in the Spark Job was an incorrectly defined argument value. Once I correct that, the error went away and the job finished. The error seems generic though, so it could be any number of configuration items.