# Mapping Data Flow failing with error on Livy State = Dead, how to resolve this?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I created a mapping data flow to process flat files and load into Snowflake. It was working fine earlier. From yesterday, I'm receiving this error and pipeline is running for like 2 hours and failing. Anyone has faced the same issue? Earlier, it used to complete in 4 minutes.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Dataflow runs on Azure Databricks. This problem occurred in the Spark when Spark cluster incorrectly defined argument value. Once you corrected that, the error will go away, and the job is finished. The error seems generic though, so it could be any number of configuration items.

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63959988/azure-synapse-analytics-exception-running-a-dataflow)

You can also Refer this [link](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/LivyServer-exception/td-p/140128)